# mysql query for this problem

Tags: mysql

hi i have a table as follows   **id,school,address,city,state,phone,email,fax** . There is almost 40 cities . I need to select 1 entry from each city. can any one guide me

example

```
city 

 a1     30 entries

 a2     12 entries

......
 a40    36 entries

 Pick 1 from each a1,a40
```

Comment: What criteria do you want to use to choose which entry from each city is selected?

Comment: Wouldn't most of the entries with the same city have the same state? Can you elaborate, please?

Comment: Ok take this as ex 10 states each have 5-6 cities each. i simply need to select an entry from each city (strictly no more than 1 from 50 to 100 entries of each city) Randomly.

Comment: In that case, "Random" would have been the correct answer to my first question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select * 
  from table_name 
 where id in (  select MAX(id) 
                  from table_name 
              group by city
             )
```

Comment: Why did this get a down vote? Sigh .. a bit crude but looks like it should work!

Answer (score 4):

In general I prefer to tackle these cases with a JOIN to a sub query, as in the following example:

```
SELECT    s.id, s.school, s.address, s.city, s.phone, s.email, s.fax
FROM      schools s
JOIN      (SELECT   MAX(id) as max_id
           FROM     schools
           GROUP BY city) sub_s ON (sub_s.max_id = s.id);
```

The `JOIN` is practically restricting your result set to entries with distinct cities. This is also assuming that you want to select the entry with the highest id when you have multiple entries for each city. If you prefer to choose the lowest id, you can use the `MIN()` aggregate function in the sub query instead of `MAX()`.

Comment: +1 for the explanation, worth much more than the query alone.

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from your_table_name group by state, city
```

and with a Random select

```
select * from your_table_name group by state, city order by rand()
```

Comment: in **mysql** this is the simplest and shortest of answer to the question. +1 to counter the downvoter(s)!

Answer (score 0):

in mysql you can simply say:

```
select * from table group by city
```

Comment: I don't think that is a good idea: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-hidden-columns.html

Comment: @mark byers: so where is the problem? the page talks about standard sql. i clearly stated i'm talking about mysql, and afaik in mysql it is possible to select columns without aggregating them. the row you get is unspecified, but you get values …

Comment: It says there "When using this feature, all rows in each group should have the same values for the columns that are ommitted from the GROUP BY part." That is not the case here.

Comment: @mark byers, quote wars! it also says »The server is free to return any value from the group, so the results are indeterminate unless all values are the same.« he wants to select any single row, _randomly_. indeterminate comes close to randomly (apart from the fact, that mysql always returns the first row found)

Comment: @mark byers, have you actually tried to run such a query in mysql?

Answer (score 0):

SELECT DISTINCT city FROM tablename